# Let $K\unlhd G$ be abelian for finite $G$, and $\Omega$, the set of all transversals of $K$ in $G$. Then $G$ acts by left multiplication on $\Omega$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group, $K$ an abelian normal subgroup and $\Omega$ the set of all transversals of $K$ in $G$. Then $G$ acts by left multiplication on $\Omega$.

That is, $(S,x)\mapsto xS$, $x\in G, S\in\Omega$ is an action, this, according to the book I'm reading. The first thing that must be checked is that it is a function into $\Omega$. Let $S=\{s_1,...,s_n\}$. Multiplication on the right of the cosets of $K$ by elements of $G$ is an action. So if $x\in G$, $\{Ks_1,...,Ks_n\}=\{Ks_1x,...,Ks_nx\}$ and $\{s_1x,...,s_nx\}$ is a transversal. But I need $\{xs_1,...,xs_n\}$ to be a transversal. I can't conquer this difficulty. With the normality of $K$ all I get is that there is no distinction between left and right transversals. $K$ being abelian serves less.

For left multiplication to be an action I also need $xyS=yxS$. This is true iff $x^{-1}y^{-1}xyS=S$. That is I should have $S^{xy}=(S^x)^y$. But I can't prove this neither. Multiplication on the right would be easier. Any hint?

Comment: Which book are you reading?

Comment: Kurzweil and Stellmacher,  The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction, p.72.

Answer (score 1):

You have described the solution yourself. There is no distinction between left and right transversals. So why not prove that it acts on the set of left transversals instead? Then you just need to show that $xs_iK=xs_jK$ implies $i=j$, and you know that.

To be an action you only need that $x(yS)=(xy)S$, no? Certainly $xyS=yxS$ if and only if the quotient $G/S$ is abelian.

Generally, if you define a group action via multiplication by things in the group, it's automatically an action. That's not a mathematical statement of course, more of a guiding principle.

Edit: I don't see personally how $K$ being abelian makes much of a difference. Or $G$ finite. Or normality of $K$, for that matter, as long as you use left transversals for a left action.

Comment: He puts $K$ abelian and normal because he is preparing some results to prove the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem. "Then you just need to show that $xs_iK=xs_jK$ implies $i=j$, and you know that.": $xs_iK=xs_jK$ gives $s_iK=s_jK$ which given $s_i,s_j\in S$ is only possible if $i=j$. This says that left multiplication of the cosets is a permutation of the cosets (I do not say it is an action) and so $\{s_iK\}=\{xs_iK\}$, which means the $xs_i$ form a transversal. That is $xS\in \Omega$.

Comment: "To be an action you only need that $x(yS)=(xy)S$, no?": in this book functions are written on the right. And an action is a function $\alpha:\Omega\times G\to \Omega$. I'll write $S^x$ meaning $(S,x)\alpha$. Then I need $S^{xy}=(S^x)^y$. That is $xyS=yxS$ should be satisfied.

Comment: Well, it won't be satisfied, so you've misunderstood. There's a footnote 2 on p57. It seems to suggest they will use left multiplication on this page, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks like they invert $x$ on p73.

Comment: You are right! So there is a typo on p.72. It should say $(S,x)\mapsto x^{-1}S$. In that case, does $S^{xy}=(S^x)^y$?

Comment: Yes!, it's immediate! Thanks a lot, David.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a typo. I think they didn't need to take products and maybe didn't want to write inverses everywhere. But it will be used with inverses